# How can I recursively set read-only permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I have a very large and deep directory. I would like to make all of it read only. The problem is I guess I have to distinguish between files (which will get `a=r`) and directories (which will get `a=rx`).

How can I do that?

Comment: I just found this: `chmod a=rX` which solves my problem.  From the `man`: (X) `execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user`

Comment: If that's intended to be an answer then it should be in an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just found this: `chmod a=rX` which solves my problem. From the man: (X) `execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user`.

Answer (score 8):

1. `chmod` accepts mode `X`, which only sets `x` to directories. **`a=X`**
2. You can also just remove the write permission: **`a-w`**

Comment: +1 for option #2, the most logical way

Comment: +1 for option 2 also, but -0.5 for misunderstanding what capital X means in chmod

Answer (score 7):

The suggestions above did not work for me, all folders were set read-only.
 
A colleague gave me this, which works:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod a-w {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find somepath \( -type f -exec chmod a=r {} \; \) -o \( -type d -exec chmod a=rx {} \; \)
```